# How can I create two matrices with meshgrid function in R?

Tags: r, matlab, matrix

I am beginer in R but I have experience in Matlab. In Matlab I could create two matrices with meshgrid function by the following way:

```
[lon, lat]=meshgrid(lon, lat)
```

where lon and lat are vectors with length_lon=424 and length_lat=412. The resulted lon and lat martices are 424x412. 
How can I carry out this method in R?
I would appreciate if you helped me!

Comment: Could you show an example? What is your final goal? You could take a look at `?outer` and `?expand.grid`. Also, see something like `matrix(lon, length(lon), length(lat)); matrix(lat, length(lon), length(lat), byrow = TRUE)`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there are R implementations of `meshgrid` available: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/pracma/docs/meshgrid or http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/AtmRay/html/meshgrid.html

Or according to this [R for MATLAB users](http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/octave-r.html) article:

[image]

I think if you want an idiomatic R solution, you should explain why you want to use `meshgrid`...